# xsd validation complains about missing attribute and wrong attribute at the same time

Tags: xml, schema, xsd-validation

I get somewhat schizophrenic behavior from xsd validation. This [link](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=e7e63665-5e0a-4387-9ecb-8dfa57d32fc5-xsdvalidation#.VVZHJXV7jUY) shows the xml and xsd + the errors in an online schema validator. When I run this locally with xmllint

```
xmllint --noout --nonet --schema devhelp2.xsd tester.devhelp2
```

I get similar warnings:

```
tester.devhelp2:5: element sub: Schemas validity error : Element '{urn:devhelp}sub', attribute 'name': The attribute 'name' is not allowed.
tester.devhelp2:5: element sub: Schemas validity error : Element '{urn:devhelp}sub', attribute 'link': The attribute 'link' is not allowed.
tester.devhelp2:5: element sub: Schemas validity error : Element '{urn:devhelp}sub': The attribute '{urn:devhelp}name' is required but missing.
tester.devhelp2:5: element sub: Schemas validity error : Element '{urn:devhelp}sub': The attribute '{urn:devhelp}link' is required but missing.
```

but this has a hint that there is something wrong with the namespace.

## PS:

I can make it validate by dropping the xmlns completely (as taken from [zvon.org](http://zvon.org/xxl/XMLSchemaTutorial/Output/ser_attributeFormDefault_st2.html)). See [here for the new online validator example](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/?save=6ee6f445-2885-4696-864e-110210edba9d-xsdvalidation#.VVtRxnV7jUY) - I'd still like to understand it though, isn't there a solution keeping the xmlns?

Comment: I've also tried adding attributeFormDefault="qualified" to my xsd, since the error is about attributes, but it does not change anything.

Comment: Is your intention to have the attributes be in the `urn:devhelp` namespace?

Comment: yes. I want 'urn:devhelp' to be the default namespace in the document.

Comment: @ensonic You should include the XML and XML Schema into your question as explained in [Help others reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Reduced example**

I reduced your example to following XML schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="urn:devhelp"
  xmlns="urn:devhelp"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:attribute name="title" type="xsd:string"/>

  <xsd:element name="book">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:attribute ref="title" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

and this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<book xmlns="urn:devhelp" title="tester Reference Manual"/>
```

**Validation errors**

> Not valid.
>   Error - Line 2, 60: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 60; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'title' is not allowed to appear in element 'book'.
>   Error - Line 2, 60: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 60; cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'title' must appear on element 'book'.

The contradicting validation errors are a good indication that something is wrong with the namespaces.

**Specification: Namespaces in XML 1.0**

The specifications states

> [6.2 Namespace Defaulting](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting)
>
> ... Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute
>   names; the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by
>   the element on which they appear.

The first clause explains that attributes won't inherit the default namespace declaration of the element. Therefore `/book/@title` has no namespace, while your XML schema requires a `title` attribute of namespace `urn:devhelp`.

The second clause is tricky, because it's easy to misunderstand. It just says that attributes won't need a namespace, because they could be used differently based on the surrounding element.

An example also mentions that behaviour:

> [6.3 Uniqueness of Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#uniqAttrs)
>
> ... However, each of the following is legal, the second because the default namespace does not apply to attribute names:
>   ...
>   <x xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org" >
>     <good a="1"     b="2" />
>     <good a="1"     n1:a="2" />
>   </x>

**Solutions**

Explicitly set a namespace for the attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<book xmlns="urn:devhelp" xmlns:mine="urn:devhelp" mine:title="tester Reference Manual"/>
```

or avoid attribute definitions outside of `complexType`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mine="urn:devhelp"
  targetNamespace="urn:devhelp"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:element name="book">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:attribute name="title" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I came to a similar solution while commuting home. I wonder it you know the justification for this. I definitely want to avoid the mine: namespace for the top-level element. But not being able to use <xsd:attribute ref ...> would miss that I can define common attributes :/

Comment: @ensonic: I don't know the reason for excluding attributes from the given namespace. Probably it was a legacy, which they didn't get rid of when they realized the inconsistency.

Comment: @ensonic: You could try to outsource the attributes into another XSD and import them like `<xs:import schemaLocation="./attr.xsd"/>` without a namespace. I'm not sure this works and I don't have an environment right now to check that.

Comment: Right now I inlined the attributes and that makes it work (https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk-doc/commit/?id=a0b6f5b205968a446f2116deeb2ef3ce0b56c60f). For attributes it is probably better to have individual ones, since then one can also document their semantics in the context of use. Thanks again, I'll release the bounty when stackoverflow lets me (7h to go) :)